# Decomposition of Matrices in Semisimple and Nilpotent Parts

Tags: linear-algebra

For any matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb F)$, where $\mathbb F$ is an algebraically closed field, there is a matrix $S\in M_n(\mathbb F)$ such that

$$SAS^{-1}=D+N,$$
where $D$ is diagonal and $N$ nilpotent. Moreover, this decomposition is unique.

Suppose now that $A\in M_n(\mathbb K)$, but $\mathbb K$ is not necessarily algebraically closed. It is also true that  there is a matrix $L\in M_n(\mathbb K)$ such that

$$LAL^{-1}=R+M,$$

where $M$ is nilpotent and $R$ is diagonalizable in the  algebraic closure of $\mathbb K$? Moreover when we consider the decomposition in $\mathbb K$ and in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb K$ the nilpotent part is the same?

Comment: I don't know. Here's what I'd try. Find a real matrix whose Jordan form is $$\pmatrix{i&1&0&0\cr0&i&0&0\cr0&0&-i&1\cr0&0&0&-i}$$ and see whather you can find your matrices $L$, $R$, and $M$.

Comment: crossposted at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/108402/decomposition-of-matrices-in-semisimple-and-nilpotent-parts